# OpenShift, python 2.7 and static files with htaccess

Tags: python, apache, .htaccess, openshift

I'm trying to configure apache to serve static files for URLs like `site.com/img/bla.jpg`.
Python cartridge + flask.

I know what there is an preconfigured alias for `wsg/static` directory, so we can use `site.com/static/bla.jpg`. But I need additional static directory.

Project structure:

```
/wsgi
  .htaccess
  /img -> $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/some/path (soft link)
  /static
  application
```

In the backend I binded `mysite.com/img/<filename>` for testing if apache or backend handles files - it returns *"ok [filename]"* string.

I have tried the following configs in htaccess:

**1**: `site.com/img/1.jpg` -> "ok 1.jpg"

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  # with and without this condition
RewriteRule ^img/(.+)$ /static/$1 [L]
# RewriteRule ^img/(.+)$ /img/$1 [L]
# RewriteRule ^/img/(.+)$ /img/$1 [L]
# RewriteRule ^img/(.+)$ https://ssl.gstatic.com/gb/images/i1_3d265689.png [L]
```

As I understand regex doesn't match request URL and apache just passes stuff to backend?

**2**: `site.com/img/1.jpg` -> "ok 1.jpg"

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule /img/1.jpg https://ssl.gstatic.com/gb/images/i1_3d265689.png [L]
```

**3**: `site.com/img/1.jpg` -> opens google's i1_3d265689.png

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule /img/1.jpg https://ssl.gstatic.com/gb/images/i1_3d265689.png [L]
```

Note: no RewriteCond.

So how to make it work?

Again I want apache to serve `mysite.com/img/<filename>` as `wsg/img/<filename>`.

Is something wrong with openshift or I miss something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like I figured out. The issue is solved in two steps:

1. All static files must be placed into `wsgi/static` if you want apache to serve them for you (and not your backend script). You can't configure apache to use another directory for that since you can manipulate only with `.htaccess` file wich is not allows to configure such stuff. So I can't make apache serve assets from `wsgi/img` or `$OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/img`. 
   I have to create symlinks to those dirs inside `wsgi/static` like:

   ```
   /wsgi
       /static
           /img -> (symlink) $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/img
   ```

   Now we can access to images via `site.com/static/img/1.jpg`.
2. Now we need map `site.com/static/img/1.jpg` to `site.com/img/1.jpg` in `wsgi/.htaccess`. Something like:

   ```
   RewriteRule ^img/(.+)$ /static/img/$1 [L]
   or
   RewriteRule ^/img/(.+)$ /static/img/$1 [L]
   ```

   And it will not work becuase regexp forces to search from the beginning of URL-path (`^`).
   Problem is what OpenShift's apache URL-path is `<wsgi app name>/%{REQUEST_URI}` (at least for `RewriteRule`). `application/img/1.jpg` in my situation. So neither `^img/(.+)$` nor `^/img/(.+)$` will not match the URL-path. I'm not an apache expert but maybe [this link](https://github.com/openshift/origin-server/blob/master/cartridges/openshift-origin-cartridge-python/usr/versions/shared/etc/conf.d/openshift.conf.erb) with template config may help someone to figure out URL-path issue.
   So solution is to remove `^`:

   ```
   RewriteRule /img/(.+)$ /static/img/$1 [L]
   ```

   Now we can use `site.com/img/1.img` but also `site.com/randomstuff/img/1.img` will work. So I use `RewriteCond` to filter such URLs.

Here is my final solution:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/img/
RewriteRule /img/(.+)$ /static/img/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thanks, you made my day. I was bashing my head against the wall with this.